# Android Architecture components : Get Activity methods when using LifecycleOwner

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

While implementing Architecture components I am facing this issue

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import android.os.Bundle
import com.reversebits.trendyvidz.R

class MainActivity : LifecycleOwner {

    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme) //This shows error
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) //This shows error
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        when {
            isNetworkAvailable() -> toast("Yes Avail")
            else -> toast("No") 
        }
    }
}
```

**How do I suppose to get Activity context-based methods here like `setContentView()` of AppCompatActivity?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out, if you want to make an Activity you need to extend Activity.

---

Other than that there is a couple of issues in your code:

### 1)

If you use support library 26.1.0+ and lifecycles 1.0.0-alpha9-1+ lifecycles are already included because

```
AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity 
FragmentActivity extends SupportActivity 
SupportActivity extends Activity implements LifecycleOwner
```

### 2)

If you use older support libraries or lifecycles you had two options.

#### 2a)

If your activity extended `FragmentActivity`, you would instead extend `LifecycleActivity` and that's it.

#### 2b)

If you couldn't do that, you'd implement `LifecycleRegistryOwner`, for example:

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleRegistryOwner {
    private final LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);

    @Override
    public LifecycleRegistryOwner getLifecycle() {
        return mLifecycleRegistry;
    }
}
```

That's where sample codes end but I don't see any code actually dispatching the events. Upon investigating current `SupportActivity` it turns out it's using `ReportFragment` to dispatch all events. Add this to properly dispatch events:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ReportFragment.injectIfNeededIn(this);
}

@CallSuper
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    this.mLifecycleRegistry.markState(State.CREATED);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

---

Another thing, this is a mistake:

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
```

The method `onCreate` triggers `ON_CREATE` event. Not the other way around. You'll get stack overflow error like this.

You use `@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)` annotation on methods, that you want to trigger automatically after `onCreate` is called, not on `onCreate` method itself.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I figured it out,
I just need to do this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LifecycleOwner {
```

As LifecycleOwner is just an interface having a single method

```
override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
        TODO("Not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

And I am able to annotate methods with this annotations after implementing LifecycleOwner.

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START) etc.
```

Comment: This means the short answer is that you forgot to extend Activity, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, just put the code in case someone wants to refer it @EugenPechanec